# Kinematic equations script fail

Tags: c#, physics, scripting, torque

I added the kinematic equations to my code and now none of it works.   I get the error rigidbody.torque assign attempt for 'Enemy' is not valid. Input torque is { 0.000000, NaN, 0.000000 }.
UnityEngine.Rigidbody:AddTorque(Vector3)
EnemyBehavour:FixedUpdate() (at Assets/_Scripts/Baddies/EnemyBehavour.cs:61)

it should be fine as far as I can tell, please help.

```
//speed of enemy
public float speed = .5f;
//base distance enemy will attack player
public float range = 3f;
//how far back enemy will stand
public float stopDistance;
//what the enemy will pursue
private GameObject target;
//targetable Enemies
private GameObject[] targetable;
//itself
private Rigidbody self;
//distance to check against
private float saveDistance;
//get the mass for physics stuff
float mass;
//gets drag for physics
float drag;
//gets angular drag for physics
float adrag;
//checks distance
float distance; 
//the player
GameObject player;
GameObject[] turrets;
//the base  
GameObject playerBase;
EnemyShoot Shoot;

void Start () {
    //get own rigidbody
    self = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    //playerbase should be obviouse
    playerBase = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Base");
    target = playerBase;

    Shoot = GetComponentInChildren<EnemyShoot> ();

    mass = self.mass;
    drag = self.drag;
    adrag = self.angularDrag;
}


void FixedUpdate () {
    target = FindFoe ();

    //checks range and 
    if (Vector3.Distance (transform.position, target.transform.position) > range || target == playerBase) {
        target = playerBase;
    }
    Vector3 acceleration = AnglularAcceleration ();
    Vector3 torque = new Vector3 (0f, acceleration.y * mass,0f);
    print (torque.ToString ());

    //look at the pursueing target
    self.AddTorque (torque);
    //move towards the pursuing target
    self.AddForce (transform.forward * speed);

}

Vector3 AnglularAcceleration () {
    // the variables to figure out
    Vector3 AnglAcc;
    float radius;
    Vector3 theta;
    float time;

    //get the radius
    radius = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, target.transform.position);
    //get the dot product between the two points
    float dot = Vector3.Dot (new Vector3 (transform.position.x, 0f, transform.position.z),new Vector3 (target.transform.position.x, 0f, target.transform.position.z));
    //get the arccosine of the angle and convert that to radians
    theta = new Vector3 (0,(Mathf.Acos(dot))*180,0);
    print (theta.ToString ());

    //now find the time
    time = (2f * theta.y) / speed;
    AnglAcc = new Vector3(0f,(speed * speed) / (2f * theta.y),0f);

    return AnglAcc;


}

//checks if turrets or player is within range
GameObject FindFoe() {
    distance = range;
    targetable = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("ETarget");

    //sets player base as default target


    foreach (GameObject test in targetable) {
        GameObject testing = test.transform.parent.gameObject;
        print (testing.ToString());
        saveDistance = Vector3.Distance (transform.position, testing.transform.position);
        if (saveDistance < distance) {
            distance = saveDistance;
            print (saveDistance.ToString());
            target = testing;
        }



    }
    return target;


}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

{ 0.000000, NaN, 0.000000 }. 
[NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112529/what-does-nan-mean-for-doubles) smell of division by zero.

check `AnglularAcceleration ()`

```
AnglAcc = new Vector3(0f,(speed * speed) / (2f * theta.y),0f);
```

AnglAcc.Y will be NaN when theta.y =0

Comment: I think the NaN could also enter one step earlier, depending on the positions used as input. If the value of `dot` goes outside the interval [-1, 1] (ie. beyond the domain of the arccosine function) then `theta.y` will become NaN, which then propagates to `AngleAcc.y` becoming NaN.